# Fail to understand why this code yields this output

Tags: python

```
a=[-5,29,45,[67,54]]
b=list(a)
a[3][0]=88
a[1]=34
print("b = ",b)
print("a = ",a)
```

When I run this python code I get the output as `b = [-5, 29, 45, [88, 54]]` and `a = [-5,34,45,[88,54]]`.
How is this output coming, I mean how is `a[3][0]=88` also getting changed in `b` whereas `a[1]=34` isn't?

Comment: for both a and b are referred to the same address. You can check id(a) and id(b), both address will be same.

Comment: b = list(a) creates a shallow (not deep) copy. Look up the difference between a shallow and a deep copy.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty simple, you have create a list out of list(a) so that creates an entirely new array. However the list within the list is the same for both a and b.

You can check it out by printing id(a), id(b), id(a[-1]) and id(b[-1)

```
a=[-5,29,45,[67,54]]
b=list(a)
a[3][0]=88
a[1]=34
print("b = ",b)
print(“a = “,a)
print(“address of a”,id(a))
print(“address of b”,id(b))
print(“address of a[-1]”, id(a[-1])
print(“address of b[-1]”, id(b[-1])
```